# Which function does dask.dataframe have, append or concat?

Tags: dask

The method for concatenating the dataframe is `append` in the online docs. But in the runtime I installed from pip, I only see `concat`. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas and Dask Dataframe both have a `concat` function and a `DataFrame.append` method